# SQL Server insert a value from a list of values

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert

I've searched extensively and can't seem to find anything, not sure if it's my search terms or not.

Either way, what I'm trying to do is get a trigger for SQL Server 2012 to update a column in an incoming record with a rotating value. For example column "Assigned" gets populated with "Josh" on the first record, "Joe" on the second record, and "James" on the third and then starts over at the beginning again on the 4th record insert.

Any help with this solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is this your actual problem or have you simplified it for the purposes of the question? either way, more context is probably required to get you to the answer

Comment: Are you looking for a pure rotation or a psuedo-random one?

Comment: Tanner, this is the actual problem that I need a solution for. I currently have a document management system that runs a MSSQL backend. When new documents arrive in the system they need to be "assigned" to a user for processing. The EDM uses a column in the MSSQL table to know who to assign it to. I am trying to create a trigger that will rotate through a list of 7 employees and assign one of them to each new document(db record) as they come in.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be to to have a table that stores the value of the next item to insert. Then let your trigger contain the logic to read and update that value once the insert has been performed. You may have to consider concurrency and locking for this to work though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an auto-incremented column (based on a sequence) and made your Assigned column as calculated base on result of [modulo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) 3.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
ADD COLUMN Assigned = 
CASE IdColumn % 3
    WHEN 0 THEN 'James'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Josh'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Joe'
END
```